Using GNU Radio Companion to measure bladeRF receiver sensitivity
We are working on a student led radio project. We want to communicate between a B200Mini and a bladeRF. We are tasked to create a link budget for this communication system. In order to do that, we need to get the receiver sensitivity. Our mentor is an analog RF guy, so SDR's are not his thing, but he tells us that receiver sensitivity is dependent on modulation scheme. We are trying to follow what he is telling us but are coming up short.
Our GFSK signal is suppose to have a baud rate of 9600 and a frequency deviation of 2400 at 435MHz (HAM band). From the wiki and other sources, these are the flow graphs we came up with to create this.
This is our transmission flow-graph:

This is our reception flow-graph:

Small edit: we have been looking at the Frequency Mod block and realize that the sensitivity should maybe be 1.57 based on this equation: Sensitivity = (2 * math.pi * deviation) / sample_rate
This obviously doesn't work. We then just did the default settings without a throttle blocks and a sample rate of 1M, and we were able to demodulate that but any changes to try to make the specific signal makes the received display not show up anymore.
How can we create the flow graph we need to make this signal?
We are sophomores with very little knowledge in RF and DSP and are trying to learn though this project. Our team went through all the tutorials on the wiki, but we are obviously missing some information. Unfortunately, our mentor isn't able to help us out with this.
We understand this is probably not a simple problem to answer, but we appreciate any and all help.

I'm not sure you should need a throttle block on the demodulator side, as long as you set samples-per-symbol correctly.

definitely shouldn't use a throttle in a hardware-limited flow graph! (If you're not getting a warning printed about that, EdEon, please tell me! There's a warning mechanism that should stop people from using throttles in flow graphs with hardware.)

A USRP can't run at 76.8 kHz sampling rate. You're definitely getting errors printed about that. I'm not sure, but I don't think the BladeRF can run at 75 kHz, either.
